# CentOS 7 Plugin "copr" can't be imported

Tags: centos, yum

In my CentOS 7 server getting `Plugin "copr" can't be imported` error message. I have installed this RPM `yum-plugin-copr-1.1.31-52.el7.noarch`

How can I fix this error message?

```
# yum copr enable
Plugin "copr" can't be imported
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No such command: copr. Please use /bin/yum --help
```

Comment: What command did you use to install the RPM?  What happens if you do `yum copr enable simc/stable` or `yum copr enable simc/stable epel-7`?

Comment: @fpmurphy I used this command. `yum -y install yum-plugin-copr`. it worked many servers, only this server giving me this error message.

Comment: @sfgroups, same configuration (version, and so on)? If others work, chances are this one is broken. Try reinstalling this package, run diagnostics on the sanity of the RPM infrastructure (databases, programs).

Comment: @vonbrand re-installing crop package didn't help. still trying to debug this issue

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've already fixed your system, but just in case I can help the next person like me who finds this question while looking for a solution, I wanted to document how I figured out what was wrong on my system. Luckily I had a working system as well to help with debugging.

On both a working and non-working system I used strace to see what files were being opened by yum:

```
strace yum update --assumeno 2>&1 | \
  egrep "^(open|stat)|copr" | \
  grep -v ENOENT | \
  sed -e 's/0x[0-9a-f]*/0xXXX/' > /tmp/copr-strace-bad
```

The first line runs strace. The second just pulls out open() or stat() call and anything referencing copr. The third line excludes all the ENOENT (file not found) results. The sed on the last line replaces a hex address parameter to stat(), which greatly reduces the number of differences when comparing the final results.

Then I used sdiff (and a really small font so I use -w to specify a wider window size) to compare the two files and see what was different.

In the end, my issue turned out to be that a copr repo I had enabled in the past had a newer python2-requests rpm which was installed as an update to python-request the first time a yum update was run after I'd enabled that repo.